# Custom namespace for code behind .aspx page

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, namespaces

I am using .NET2.0. Let's say a have a simple aspx form with txtInput and btnSomeAction

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnSomeAction" runat="server" CommandName="SomeAction" Text="Do"/>
```

Then within the code behind the form I have

```
Protected Sub btnSomeAction_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSomeAction.Click
    Dim s As String
    s = txtInput.Text
End Sub
```

It all works fine.

Then I want to add the code to a custom namespace like

```
Namespace mycustomnamespace
```

When doing that I would get a complier error:

***Name 'txtInput' is not declared***  - as if the code was no longer connected to the page

Do i need to modify the aspx page to include the namespace?, What about the partial class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do i need to modify the aspx page to include the namespace?, What about the partial class?

Yes.  At the top of your aspx file you should see something like

> ```
> <%@ Page AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Blah.Foo.Bar" %>
> ```

Where bar is the name of the class in the codebehind and Blah.Foo is it's namespace.  You would need to change it to

> ```
> <%@ Page AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="mycustomnamespace.Bar" %>
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Now when I choose "View Code Gen File" from the page menu the generated code includes the custom namespace

Comment: Also it seems that I needed to add the projectname on top of the namespace like Inherits="MyProjectName.mycustomnamespace.Bar"